# MVC - A place for common functions?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I've just started to look into MVC and I'm pretty new. I would like to port procedural code across to it but I'm struggling (please no-one suggest to use a Framework).

I can understand how it works, but understanding is different to doing. In my procedural code, I have several functions such as message(). These are called if the user does not have permission to view the current page, for example.

My problem is adding this into MVC. I've added Twig so far and I've managed to render some Twig on the index page but using functions such as message before was as easy as this:

```
message('Message Text');
```

Adding it to the controller directory would allow it to be accessed as a web page, which I don't want. And through the model, I'm not sure how to do this without requiring the file first. I could use a function, but I don't want globals and this is partly why I'm changing.

How can I properly place commonly used functions?

**Edit**

What I'm using is a modified version of this: http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html

Comment: You could use layer inheritance to perform this task. You could also use helpers (the web is full of references for this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to think of traditional `MVC` like this:

A controller is my business logic to implement my product.
A model is the code to represent data.
A view is what represents my product.

Under this paradigm, `what represents my product` is what an end-user sees.
So if it's a UX component, it's part of the view.

In this way, it's pretty easy to figure out how to use it:

1. You could `use path/to/notifications.php` and then `$notifications = new Notifications();` where `notifications.php` is a class facilitating messages like you reference.
2. You could `extends Notifications` on your view (or even a base view!) so that ANY view you instantiate immediately has access to your notifications class.
3. You could (though probably shouldn't) `require_once( 'path/to/notifications.php' );` and then the class or functions therein would be available. Again, you probably shouldn't do it this way

The bottom line is this:

- Place your old procedural code in a well organized class. It might be named something like `Notifications` if that's what the code does. The important thing is to organize well, name well, and do not try to force too much code into one thing.
- Use that class in your code. You can explicitly use it's namespace and `new` an instance of it, or you can extend it to bring it along as the parent class of your view.

Comment: At any MVC implementation you will probably have his problem: How do we deal with constants, common functions/methods and stuff? A common approach is to use "helper" classes (or modules, files, etc) that provide such functionality. Another one is providing a configuration file. Another one is configuring singletons, etc. At any point, you will end requiring files outside of your model, and that's perfectly fine. One of the "best" things of MVC is that it's oriented to modularize and split view from business logic, as you said. It's functionality oriented more than "file" oriented.

Comment: In other words: `require()`s are fine, as long as you use them to continue programming in an "MVC way" (I mean: objects, messaging between them, encapsulation of **their characteristics**, etc). Maybe taking a look at CodeIgniter's MVC helpers implementation (http://www.codeigniter.com/) would give some ideas. It's basically a mix of classes and procedural functions in a framework. It doesn't "break" the MVC for **the app**, though.

Comment: @rockerest I've tried the class option as you suggested and I passed the registry through the functions class on the index.php page when I'm loading the router .etc.

I'm not entirely satisfied with the loading of it, but I'm really impressed with the processing side once it has been loaded.

Comment: @Chris98 - Here's a [very simple autoloader](https://github.com/rockerest/nox/blob/master/components/system/Preload.php) that I wrote a long while ago. Once code like this has run, you don't need to explicitly register classes again as long as you consistently organize them. In this case, as long as the file I was trying to autoload was in my `APPLICATION_INCLUDE_PATH` the autoloader function found and required it. This particular implementation is rudimentary and naive, but it might be helpful to look into PHP autoloading and see how the big names are doing it.

Comment: Thanks - another question now (sorry if these seem basic)

How could I include a common header/footer? Currently, I require header/footer.php and that send the header. But how would this be accomplished in an MVC way?